# How to prove $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^N}{2^k}\leq c\mathbb{E}[X^N]$ where $X$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $\ln(2)$?

Tags: expectation, exponential-distribution, polylogarithm

I came across the series $$A(N):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^N}{2^k},~~N\in\mathbb{N},N\geq 4,$$
which is the polylogarithm of order $-N$ evaluated at $\frac{1}{2}$.

I got the hint that this can be bounded in terms of the $N-$th moment of an exponentially distributed random variable $X$ with parameter $\ln(2)$.

Indeed, if I approximate the corresponding integral by a Riemann- sum, something close to the target expression turns up: For $B>0$, we have

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb{E}[X^N]&=&\ln(2)\int_{0}^\infty x^N2^{-x}\ \mathrm{d}x\\
&\geq&\ln(2)\int_{0}^B x^N 2^{-x}\ \mathrm{d}x\\
&=&\ln(2)\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty,n\geq B}\frac{B}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\left(k\frac{B}{n}\right)^N}{2^{k\frac{B}{n}}}\\
&\geq&\ln(2)\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty,n\geq B}\left(\frac{B}{n}\right)^{N+1}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^N}{2^{k}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
So far I couldn't get closer to the solution. Do you have an idea?

Of course, I am also open to any other approach for finding the desired bound, i.e. a bound of the form
$$A(N)\leq c^N N!$$
For example, I tried the representation of the polylogarithm that uses the Stirling numbers of the second kind, but didn't get as ``far'' as above.

Comment: On each interval $(k,k+1)$, $x^N\geqslant k^N$ and $2^{-x}\geqslant2^{-k-1}$ hence $$E(X^N)\geqslant\ln2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_k^{k+1}x^N2^{-x}dx\geqslant\ln2\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^N2^{-k-1}=c\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^N}{2^k}$$ with $$c=\frac{\ln2}2$$ On the other hand, $$E(X^N)=\frac{N!}{(\ln2)^N}$$ hence all this proves that $$A(N)\leqslant\frac{2\cdot N!}{(\ln2)^{N+1}}$$

Comment: Great, thank you!